# Xamarin beep Android not supported exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, beep

I'm trying to use the beep function in Xamarin, referred to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Console.Beep()/) article.

But when I call that function I do get an error message:

> An unhandled exception occurred.

I hope someone here can push me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should use a Try / Catch to catch the exception and try to understand the problem

Comment: Please add a stacktrace of the exception to your question!

Comment: I've added the exception. I hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

The exception say that you can't use Beep because it's not supported. You can try to play a sound

Add a sub folder named raw under Resources.

Add a file named test.mp3 under raw.

In the Activity, create a class variable for the MediaPlayer.

```
MediaPlayer _player;
```

In the OnCreate method, call MediaPlayer.Create(), passing the context and the resource identifier for the mp3.

```
_player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.test);
```

Call the Start method of the MediaPlayer.

```
_player.Start();
```

[PlaySound](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio/)